# Why C# Monitor class implementation for lock statement have try-finally only but not catch?

Tags: c#, locking, monitor

Why C# Monitor class implementation for lock statement have try-finally only but not catch ?

```
var obj = new object();
try
{
  Monitor.Enter(obj);
}
finally 
{
  Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

Comment: Because there would be nothing useful to do on a `catch` / Exception. Thus it lets the exception propagate normally. However, there *is* cleanup that should always be done - hence the 'finally'.

Comment: What would that catch do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have posted some code to explain what you mean...

Generally the reason why you have a `finally` but no `catch` is because you have some code you want run when the scope (the `try`) is exited regardless of how the exit happens.

In other words, whoever wrote the code doesn't care what exception is thrown (if any) because they are not dealing with it right then (it will just bubble up to the next level of code), but whatever is in the `finally` will always be run whether there was an exception or not.

Comment: @rajibdotnet The answer remains unchanged, the reasoning is still the same.

Comment: Thanks @slugster, but I cannot rationalize the rating of -1

Comment: @rajibdotnet It wasn't me who down voted you, I would suggest that it was because someone didn't like the original form of your question. Don't worry about it, I've had perfectly good questions down voted for no reason, it happens.